# Android minus time have bug in calculate 12 to 13

Tags: android, date, time

I have two times, I want to get their difference.
my times : 
start : 2017-12-12 13:19:21
end   : 2017-12-12 12:59:48

so i format them and minus them like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2017-12-12 13:19:21");
        Date endDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2017-12-12 12:59:48");

        second = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

it works well if first time and second time are not before 12 and after 12

for example start in 10:30, another in 11:02, it works fine.
but if they are in such mood like above code : start 12:59 and end 13:19, the difference calculate wrong for 12 hours.
the result of above code calculated: 12 hours and 20 minutes, but should be just 20 minutes,
where is the bug, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), if you want to have the hours in the 24-hours format, you have to use **HH** instead of **hh**.

That should solve your problem.